# When button is clicked, need to download canvas and increment sql integer by 1

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, canvas

I have been able to get my button to download the file (html canvas), but I need it to also increment a SQL field by one.

I am not sure how much code you will need, so I will begin by giving you the parts I am trying to get to talk to each other.

**PHP:**

```
$insert = mysql_query("update UserName set logins = logins+1 where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
```

**HTML Button:**

```
<div>
<a id="dload" download="YourFileName.png">Download as image</a>
</div>
```

**JAVA (On the same page as button)**

```
function download() {
var dt = c5.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
this.href = dt;
};

function insert(){
var insert = <?php $insert; ?>;
};

dload.addEventListener('click', download, false);
dload.addEventListener('click', insert, false);
```

The PHP code lives on a file called login.php as a variable. Login.php is included on the file that contains the HTML button and Java above.

The download part works. The SQL query is correct and works when run on the database. But I am just not sure how to integrate so it both downloads and adds one to the database.

Thanks for looking.

**EDIT:**

I can now get it to do both, but now it only increments the SQL field once per logon (will download every time though). The user needs to logout , then log back in for it to work properly again. I need it to increment by one every time they click download.

I changed this:

```
function download() {
var dt = c5.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
this.href = dt;
};

function insert(){
var insert = <?php $insert; ?>;
};

dload.addEventListener('click', download, false);
dload.addEventListener('click', insert, false);
```

to this (which is what I had originally):

```
function download() {
var dt = c5.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
this.href = dt;
};
dload.addEventListener('click', download, false);
```

And changed my button to this:

```
echo <a id="dload" download="YourFileName.png" value="<?php echo $insert; ?>">Download as image</a>
```